# Django SSL server

Tags: django-sslify

I am using Django 2.2,  I want to enable https in it.

I have installed Django-SSL server and I have the certificate and the private key.

I am running the script like:

```
python manage.py runsslserver --certificate /path/to/certificate.pem --key /path/to/key.key
```

when I am running the above command the server is running like:

```
Starting development server at https://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using SSL certificate: C:\Users\djangotutorial\myvenv\lib\site-packages\sslserver\certs\certificate.pem
Using SSL key: C:\Users\djangotutorial\myvenv\lib\site-packages\sslserver\certs\key.key
```

but when I am opening the link it is showing the unsecure connection.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Cause you have used a self-singed ssl certificate, just ingore the warning and you'll got your web page.